# CSS float right - not clear how computed height and margins work

Tags: css, html

Why is this HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .left { background-color: yellow; }
            .right { float: right;  background-color: lightgray; width: 150px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>right</p>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <p>left</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

... resulting in `div.right` being taller (height is greater) than `div.left` (in FF and chrome):
[image]

Comment: because you are floating the `right div` and not the `left div`. this means that the `margin` on the `p` is inside the `right div` while for your `left div` it sits on the outside of the `div`

Comment: If the question is *why* and not *how fix it* I think Andrew's is the best answer.

Comment: @Arkana: Correct. Someone should read before downvoting ;-)

Comment: @Sammy No one can downvote comments

Comment: Mr. Alien: The question was downvoted! Anyway, I now know what I wanted to know.

Comment: Can I somehow 'Accept' the comment?

Comment: You can't, in this case you can request the answerer (@Andrew in this case) to post his comment as answer ;)

Comment: I posted it as an answer. @Arkana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing here is the interaction between collapsing margins and floats.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="right">
        <p>right</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <p>left</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is basically what you have except for the wrapper element.

Now look at the CSS:

```
.wrap {
    outline: 2px dotted red;
    padding: 1px;
}
p {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    margin: 2.00em 0;
}
.left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 150px;
}
```

I added `.wrap` with 1px padding to make sure that you can see the effects of the margins.

Now here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9hhkk/

What you see here is both text on the same baseline with the right floated text to the right as you expect.  Both the left and right elements have the same margins.

In your example, the top margin of the `.left` collapsed with the top margin of the its containing block.  However, the `.right` element is floated, and the margins of the floated element do not collapse, so you see the extra padding.

I set up my demo so that the margins do not collapse for the in-flow element.

Answer (score 2):

Reset your `<p>` tag.

```
p {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

More on reseting CSS.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

because you are floating the `right div` and not the `left div`. this means that the `margin` on the `p` is inside the `right div` while for your `left div` it sits on the outside of the `div`